# How to login in Meteor.loginWithPassword with username

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried to login in Meteor with username instead of email but it is not working.

```
 Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, error => {
   // error ==> user not found
});
```

According to [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn) it says user can be either username, email or id

I have saved username in profile of User

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I saved my username in profile sections. Username should be saved as separate key just like email, then it will work